# pentaho spoon/kettle merge row diff step

Tags: pentaho, kettle, data-integration

I want to update a new database's table based on an old one

this is the data in the old table:

id,type
1,bla
2,bla bla

the new table is empty. Currently i have the two `input table` steps connected to a `merge rows diff` step and then funnel that into a `sync after merge` step.

the issue is that I get the flagfield set to `deleted` because it cannot find the any values in the compare stream (duh its an empty table!). Is my logic wrong or should it not work like this:

not found in compare stream --> set flag to `needs insert` --> insert in compare table ??

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I set the `insert when value equal` field in the advanced tab of the `sync after merge` step to "deleted". It now inserted it into the table

Comment: In the Merge step, if you change what is the reference data, it will also reverse the flags

Comment: yeah that's what i figured after re-re-re-reading the docs that what I want to compare is the other way around... essentially use the new database as a base and compare the old one against it... therefore empty vs full makes needs update